# Windows Phone - Listbox items on array

Tags: c#, collections, listbox, windows-phone

I have a Listbox on my Windows Phone app, the listbox receive values from collection. I put the Listbox items on array. So, I need get value the first list item, but i received the value `App1.PivotPage1+Fields`.

The collection item i want show is `FNome`. How do it?

My Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] array = new string[List2.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < List2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            object s = List2.Items[i];
            array[i] = s.ToString();
        }

        TJSONObject jObject = new TJSONObject();
        TJSONPair jPair = new TJSONPair("test", array[0]);
        TJSONPair jPair1 = new TJSONPair("test1", "test1");
        TJSONArray jArray = new TJSONArray();

        jObject.addPairs(jPair);
        jObject.addPairs(jPair1);
        jArray.add(jObject);


        MessageBox.Show(jArray.ToString());

    }
```

My collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Fields> Items { get; set; }

    public class Fields
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FId")]
        public int FId { get; set; }

        public string FNome { get; set; }
        public float FEstado1 { get; set; }
        public string FPais { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string lero { get; set; }
        public string Quantity1 { get; set; }
        public string FEstado { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is working fine now. I only changed this code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string[] array = new string[List2.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < List2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        object s = List2.Items[i];
        array[i] = s.ToString();
    }

    TJSONObject jObject = new TJSONObject();
    TJSONPair jPair = new TJSONPair("test", array[0]);
    TJSONPair jPair1 = new TJSONPair("test1", "test1");
    TJSONArray jArray = new TJSONArray();

    jObject.addPairs(jPair);
    jObject.addPairs(jPair1);
    jArray.add(jObject);


    MessageBox.Show(jArray.ToString());

}
```

For this:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Fields[] array = List2.Items.Cast<Fields>().ToArray();

        TJSONObject jObject = new TJSONObject();
        TJSONPair jPair = new TJSONPair("FNome", array[0].FNome);
        TJSONPair jPair1 = new TJSONPair("test1", "test1");
        TJSONArray jArray = new TJSONArray();

        jObject.addPairs(jPair);
        jObject.addPairs(jPair1);
        jArray.add(jObject);

        MessageBox.Show(jArray.ToString());
}
```